# Reduce number of joins on same table

Tags: mysql, join, pivot

I have two tables:

ranking_history

```
| user_id | ranking | time
|    1    |  2      | 2018-05-21     
|    1    |  5      | 2018-04-28
|    2    |  9      | 2018-05-21     
|    2    |  1      | 2018-04-28
```

user

```
| id | ranking 
| 1  |  7     
| 2  |  3
```

I need to join these two tables to produce a table look like this:

```
| id | ranking | last_weeks_ranking | last_months_ranking 
| 1  |  7      |     2              |    5  
| 2  |  3      |     9              |    1
```

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT *, r1.ranking as last_weeks_ranking, r2.ranking as last_months_ranking 
from user 
left join ranking_history r1 on user.id = r1.user_id where r1.time = '2018-05-21' 
left join ranking_history r2 on user.id = r2.user_id where r2.time = '2018-04-28'
```

The output is OK but I need to join one table twice. Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: You could simply your data by eliminating the special case of `user.ranking` and instead storing the current ranking in `ranking_history`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+pivot

Comment: @Schwern You are right but still will need do the pivot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
  SELECT user.id,
         MAX(user.ranking) as ranking,
         MAX(CASE WHEN r1.time = '2018-05-21' THEN r1.ranking END) as last_weeks_ranking,
         MAX(CASE WHEN r1.time = '2018-04-28' THEN r1.ranking END) as last_months_ranking
  FROM user
  JOIN ranking_history r1 
    ON user.id = r1.user_id 
  GROUP BY user.id
```

Comment: This query does exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Other approach is using co-related subqueries:

```
SELECT 
   user.id, 
   user.ranking,
   (SELECT 
        ranking_history.ranking 
    FROM 
        ranking_history
    WHERE
        ranking_history.user_id = user.id
        AND ranking_history.time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ORDER BY 
        ranking_history.time ASC
    LIMIT 1) AS last_weeks_ranking,
   (SELECT 
        ranking_history.ranking 
    FROM 
        ranking_history
    WHERE
        ranking_history.user_id = user.id
        AND ranking_history.time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ORDER BY 
        ranking_history.time ASC    
    LIMIT 1) AS last_months_ranking    
FROM 
    user
```

**PS:** I added dynamic date calculation for the columns `last_weeks_ranking` and  `last_months_ranking` instead off using fixed values '2018-05-21' and '2018-04-28'

**Result**

```
| id | ranking | last_weeks_ranking | last_months_ranking |
+----+---------+--------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       7 |                  2 |                   5 |
|  2 |       3 |                  9 |                   1 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f8e2c/9